# How to handle AES 256 encryption using jmeter?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to run the script in jmeter but do not know how to handle the AES 256 encryption used for password. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform whatever encoding operations you want using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) via [Java Cryptography API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html), example code for [AES 256 encryption](https://javainterviewpoint.com/aes-256-encryption-and-decryption/) would be something like:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

def textToEncrypt = 'foo'
def secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE")
def key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES")
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(secret.getBytes("UTF-8")))
vars.put('encrypted', cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")).encodeBase64() as String)
```

Demo:

[image]